# When `HttpGet` handling `Create` action method just returns `View()`, why doesn't the javascript validation get triggered on the browser?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

When `HttpGet` handling `Create` action method just returns `View()`, it causes all form fields to be uninitialized.

Why javascript validation does not get triggered when users views the blank form?

Answer (score 3):

I don't really know the inner workings, but I'll give it a guess ;-)

First of all, it has nothing to do with whether or not its an `[HttpGet]` or a `[HttpPost]` -- that's just the way it usually works.

Your average `[HttpGet]` methods look something like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index() {
    // Get some data from the database
    return View(data);
}
```

There aren't any parameters in this method, because we want the user to hit this controller when they just type in the URL (i.e. `Home/Index`).

Your usual `[HttpPost]` method might look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(MyModel myModel) {
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
         // Do stuff
    }
    else
    {
        return View(myModel);
    }
}
```

I believe the validation attributes aren't triggered until you actually bind the form values to the model and hit that Create(...) controller. If your `[HttpGet]` happened to take in a model as a parameter, then validation would get triggered at that point as well.

When you return the View with the existing, **invalid** model, somehow the `ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SomeProperty)` method knows that the validation for that property failed. That's the part I'm not sure about.

By contrast, when you return a new `View()` as the ActionResult (as you usually do for an HTTP GET), a brand-new, shiny model is instantiated. Creating a new model is just as simple as creating a POCO (Plain Old C# Object) -- the validation is not triggered.

As for the client-side validation, that is handled completely through JavaScript once you click the form's submit button. When your `[HttpGet]` request displays the blank form, the submit button hasn't yet been clicked (so the JavaScript validation hasn't been started). In addition, I believe that once you begin typing the validation also kicks in through various JavaScript events such as `change`, `keydown`, `keypress`, etc.

Comment: @Pandincus: Thank for answering. I will wait for other answers. Your answer is of course great. :D

Comment: @Recycle Bin - Thanks! Sure, definitely wait. I'm actually kind of new at MVC and just took a guess based on some stuff I've been playing around with. I'm sure some MVC ninja will get in here soon and blow my answer to shreds ;-)
Either way, hope it helps!

Comment: Good answer.  As for the JS side, you have to have client validation enabled.  Once enabled, they will happen automatically for each `ValidationMessageFor` property you specified.  The validation does not get triggered on the initial blank form because the user has not attempted to edit any thing.  As soon as you input an invalid value, you'll see a validation message.

Comment: @Matthew - Thanks! I'll incorporate that into my answer. Do you know if the client-side validation just hits the server asynchronously to perform validation, or does the ASP.NET MVC script include built-in validators for the basic annotations (i.e. [Required], [Range], etc)?

Comment: @Pandincus - The client side validation is fully implemented in javascript via jQuery.  [Here's a good article](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html).

Answer (score 2):

The form validation routines will only run if the `ModelState` is not valid, and then the `ValidationMessageFor` helpers  use the `ModelState.Errors` collection to work out if their field in the model is invalid.

So if you return a view with no model data, and therefore no model state, there are no errors to trigger the validation.

Answer (score 1):

In Rails the answer is because validations are only called on save. I imagine the answer is the same or similar here.

Comment: OK. Thanks for answering. I am waiting for other answers from asp.net-mvc people.

Comment: fair enough :) I imagine this is a commonality between MVC designed frameworks, I am curious myself if it is.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled Have you enabled client validation correctly?

```
@{ Html.EnableClientValidation(); }
```

or using config

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

Javascript validation gets hooked up to the submit event for the form. Loading an empty form doesn't fire that event on the user's browser.